# How do I count the number of times a word occurs using Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I have just started using visual basic and wanted to create a program that counted the number of times a word appeared. My plan was develop a program that analyses a sentence that contains several words without punctuation. When 
a word in that sentence is input, the program identifies all of the positions where the word occurs in the sentence.

I started by making a code that counted the amount of spaces in a sentence but am now stuck.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Sentence As String
        Dim SentenceLength As Integer
        Dim Text As String
        Console.WriteLine("ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY")

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your word ") : Sentence = Console.ReadLine

        Dim TextCounter As Integer = 0
        Dim MainWord As String = Sentence
        Dim CountChar As String = " "
        Do While InStr(MainWord, CountChar) > 0
            MainWord = Mid(MainWord, 1 + InStr(MainWord, CountChar), Len(MainWord))
            TextCounter = TextCounter + 1

            Text = TextCounter + 2
            Console.WriteLine(Text)

        Loop


        Console.WriteLine(TextCounter)

        Console.Write("Press Enter to Exit")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Just use `String.Split` to split the string and count the occurences of the word, or use a Regex to find all occurences of the word

Comment: BTW Mid, InStr, Len etc, exist only for compatibility with VB6. The `String` class has far more powerful functions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The important and useful difference is that Mid, InStr, Len etc all correctly work even if the string variable contains null. All String methods will throw an NRE.

Comment: @CSerg this calls for a null check and a replacement with an empty array, *NOT* ignoring the smelly code that produced the null value in the first place. What you call "correctly handling null" is actually a problem because it propagates invalid values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick & dirty method is to split the string into an array of strings, then count how many times a word appears in it:

```
Dim words() As String = Sentence.Split(new char() {" ", ",", ".", ";"} ' add other punctuation as appropriate 
Dim count = words.Count(Function(word) word = MainWord)
```

This uses the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) method to split the string each time a space is encountered. Then it uses the [Enumerable.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method to count the words that match a certain condition, that the word is equal to `MainWord`

Answer (score 0):

To count substrings:

```
Dim count = UBound(Split("catty cat", "cat")) ' 2
```

To count words:

```
Dim countWords = Regex.Matches("catty cat", "\bcat\b").Count ' 1
```